# c# datetime format (yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:00) for google chart date

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, google-visualization

I am about to show .NetCore data into google chart. Date format is datetime.

```
public List<object[]> GetProdVal()
{
    List<object[]> value = new List<object[]>();
    foreach (var item in valuelist)
    {
        object[] val = {
        item.Date,
        item.TotalCost
        };
        value.Add(val);
    }
    return value;
}
```

When I consider Date format as string in google chart it returns the value and works well.

```
  prodval_chartData = @Json.Serialize(ViewBag.productionvalue, new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings {
                StringEscapeHandling =Newtonsoft.Json.StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml});

var prodval_data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            prodval_data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
            prodval_data.addColumn('number', 'Total');
            prodval_data.addRows(prodval_chartData);
```

but when I change the format to date I receive below error:

```
Uncaught Error: Type mismatch. Value 2018-04-22T00:00:00 does not match type date in column index 0
```

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve] so that we can run your code and see the error?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public List<object[]> GetProdVal()
{
    List<object[]> value = new List<object[]>();
    foreach (var item in valuelist)
    {
        object[] val = {
        $"new Date('{item.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss")}')",
        item.TotalCost
        };
        value.Add(val);
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, problem is still remained, When I change google chart column type to date it doesn't return anything and gives the same error. :( When I change the type to string it returns for example new Date('2018-05-18T12:00:00')

Comment: So, please add to your question the value of prodval_chartData variable. To help us to see any formatting issue. Because the Google DataTable data providen should be an array of an array. You can algo change the result type of your function to object[][] and return the result as "return value.ToArray()". Probably will work in complement to my answer

Answer (score 0):

I managed to sort out the issue as below:

Controller:

```
    public List<object[]> GetProdVal()
    {
        List<object[]> value = new List<object[]>();
        foreach (var item in valuelist)
        {
            DateTimeConvertor dtc = new DateTimeConvertor();
            double.TryParse(dtc.Year(item.Date.ToString()), out double year);
            double.TryParse(dtc.Month(item.Date.ToString()), out double month);
            double.TryParse(dtc.Day(item.Date.ToString()), out double day);
            object[] val = {
            year,
            month,
            day,                
            item.TotalCost
            };
            value.Add(val);
        }
        return value;
    }
```

View:

```
        prodval_chartData = @Json.Serialize(ViewBag.productionvalue, new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings {
            StringEscapeHandling =Newtonsoft.Json.StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml});

      var prodval_data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        prodval_data.addColumn('number', 'year');
        prodval_data.addColumn('number', 'month');
        prodval_data.addColumn('number', 'day');
        prodval_data.addColumn('number', 'Total');
        prodval_data.addRows(prodval_chartData);
        //Insert new column for generated date:
        prodval_data.insertColumn(0, 'date', 'Date');
        //Count number of iterations:
        var count = prodval_data.getNumberOfRows();

        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            //Read year, month, day and calculate date
            var year = prodval_data.getValue(i, 1);
            var month = prodval_data.getValue(i, 2)-1;
            var day = prodval_data.getValue(i, 3);

            var date = new Date(year, month, day);

            prodval_data.setValue(i, 0, date);
        }
        // remove columns of year, month, day
        prodval_data.removeColumn(1);
        prodval_data.removeColumn(1);
        prodval_data.removeColumn(1);
```